# bash getopts not able to recognize arguments

Tags: linux, bash, awk, getopts

We have a `getopts` script to retrieve the arguments as below

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":d:l:f:o:" OPT;
do
    echo 'In Test Script - Got Options '$OPT ' with' $OPTIND ' and ' $OPTARG
    case $OPT in
        d)
            echo $OPTARG;;
        f)
            echo $OPTARG;;
        l)
            echo $OPTARG;;
        ?)
            echo $OPTARG;;
    esac
done
```

We receive an argument which is parsed in another script and passed to the `getopts` script and it works fine for single entry e.g. `12345,-d somedesc -l somelabel`

```
#!/bin/bash
INFO="12345,-d somedesc -l somelabel"
ID=`echo "$INFO" | awk -F "," "{ print $"1" }"`
OPTIONS=`echo "$INFO" | awk -F "," "{ print $"2" }"`
sh test.sh $OPTIONS
```

However, we receive multiple entries e.g. `12345,-d somedesc -l somelabel:6789, -d anotherdesc -l anotherlabel` and are using `loop` and `awk` to split the arguments further in which case the `getopts` does not get triggered even though the OPTIONS are correctly passed.

```
#!/bin/bash
INFO="12345,-d somedesc -l somelabel:6789, -d anotherdesc -l anotherlabel"
IFS=":"
set $INFO
echo 'Parsing INFO '$INFO
for item
do
    echo 'Item is '$item
    #parsing each item to separate id and options
    ID=`echo "$item" | awk -F "," "{ print $"1" }"`
    echo 'ID is '$ID
    OPTIONS=`echo "$item" | awk -F "," "{ print $"2" }"`
    echo 'Invoking Test Script with '$OPTIONS
    sh test.sh $OPTIONS
done
```

Any reason the `getopts` is not able to recognize the OPTIONS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem is that you're changing value of IFS** on top of your script to colon `:` and then passing arguments to your script `test.sh` while IFS is still set to `:`. Which in effect is being called as:

1st time:

```
sh test.sh "-d somedesc -l somelabel"
```

and 2nd time:

```
sh test.sh " -d anotherdesc -l anotherlabel"
```

Thus making argument list into a **single argument** and getops fails.

What you need to do is to save original IFS before you set it to colon and restore it after set command like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
INFO="12345,-d somedesc -l somelabel:6789, -d anotherdesc -l anotherlabel"
# save IFS value
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=":"
set $INFO
# restore saved IFS value
IFS=$OLDIFS

echo 'Parsing INFO '$INFO
for item
do
    echo 'Item is '$item
    #parsing each item to separate id and options
    ID=`echo "$item" | awk -F "," "{ print $"1" }"`
    echo 'ID is '$ID
    OPTIONS=`echo "$item" | awk -F "," "{ print $"2" }"`
    echo 'Invoking Test Script with '$OPTIONS
    sh test.sh $OPTIONS
done
```

Comment: even after restoring the IFS value getopts is not able to reconize the individual arguments. The echos from test.sh are not printed.

Comment: On what platform are you testing? I have tested it multiple times before posting.

Comment: Red Hat 4.1.2-50 - Linux version 2.6.18-308.el .. Let me check on other machines and revert back.

Comment: In any case one thing you should do first. Instead of `sh test.sh $OPTIONS` use `bash test.sh $OPTIONS` since you're using bash.